# How to install ubuntu from iso on hard disk itself?

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

I've already got a fully functional ubuntu workstation up and running.
Now in case i have to reinstall ubuntu due to some reason or other, i want to have an entry on the **grub** menu itself that points to the **iso's location on the hard drive**, maybe on a completely separate partition.
And when i select that option it should boot from that iso and function exactly as if i'd booted from an install cd.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to boot live iso images?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141940/how-to-boot-live-iso-images)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you create a separate partition and place Ubuntu Live CD contents in it, it should be bootable, but I dont think a simple `sudo update-grub` would be enough to add an entry to GRUB. You would have to manually create the entry in GRUB's configuration file. In this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2) you should have the necessary information to do that.