# Use one USB drive for 3 purposes: Ubuntu OS/recovery installation/data

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, usb

I have a high performance USB drive and decided to use it for multiple purposes:

1. it should have an OS installed in, like Ubuntu (I now use server version for a lighter weight OS), then when I boot from this drive it can start the OS in it.
2. it should act as a recovery disk, so I can use this one to install a new Ubuntu on other machines: when I start another machine and set to boot from this disk it can let me start installation process.
3. it can be used as a portable data disk so I can copy & paste data: when I plug it in another running machine then that machine can identify the disk (it doesn't matter if there are multiple partitions identified) and let me use the disk to transfer data.

May I stuff all these in one USB drive? Task 1 & 2 seem conflicting, but I was thinking maybe I can partition the disk into 3 partitions, and let each partition for one task only. What should I do to get all three? What file format should the three partitions have? (I would prefer exFat for all, but not sure if that is okay)

Personally, I know what to do for each of the task alone, but feel quite puzzled on how to get all three together. My current tools include: a PC with windows in, a PC with Ubuntu, and a laptop with Mac OS. If the task has to be performed in one of the three major OSes and also some system tools need to be installed, I can install them, too.

UPDATE: 
- If a solution exists that do not require partitioning the disk, that is also fine.
- I would prefer not to use YUMI, but GRUB.

I'm sorry if my question sounds ignorant! But thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a USB stick that has a permanent Ubuntu install with other bootable ISOs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592329/can-i-create-a-usb-stick-that-has-a-permanent-ubuntu-install-with-other-bootable)