# Installing Ubuntu on a internal ssd externally

Tags: system-installation, ssd, adapter

I would like to install Ubuntu on a system with no os. I do not have a flash drive or an optical drive, but I do have a ssd to USB adapter. I was wondering if on another computer it is possible to install Ubuntu (or any modern distro) to the SSD using that adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Your ssd To usb will work like a flash drive.  You can copy the iso to it like you would do with a flash drive and boot on it like any flash drive.

The way to copy it depends of you other computer's OS.

Comment: Most installers assume a small USB flash drive and totally erase it and make one FAT32 partition. If you have any data you want to keep you may not want to use any standard installers. But then it is a bit more complicated. Probably  easiest to just purchase a small flash drive. But they are so inexpensive now a larger one could then also be used to backup data. You can manually partition, manually install grub and boot ISO directly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/845192/can-i-create-a-dedicated-partition-for-gparted-and-launch-from-grub

Comment: I believe the OP did not want to install the live installer to that SSD but perform a full installation to SSD for use in another computer.

Comment: @Takkat Oh! you it seems you are right!.. Miss reading... but it will also works.