# How to create a multiboot USB that allows persistence, non-persistence and data partition?

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, portable, mkusb

I want a complete guide to make a generic multiboot USB.

**Requests:**

- Multiple iso boots;
- Multiple persistent boots (unlimited size);
- One partition to data storage;

**What I've tried:**

[MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?) only lets 1 persistent ISO.

[MultiBootUsb](http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/) limits your persistent storage to 4GB, no partition for data (still good)

`mkusb` More than 4GB persistent storage, data partition, but single boot.

*Correct me if I'm wrong.*

***What can be done so far is accepted.***

Comment: I am not a fan of persistence, just  do a full install of Ubuntu to any flash drive 16GB or more, have at least one data partition. Have used gpt with BIOS or UEFI boot. And then in data partition have added many ISO files to directly boot from grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/845192/can-i-create-a-dedicated-partition-for-gparted-and-launch-from-grub and: ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive(or really any drive) - drs305 Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples
& https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: You are right about mkusb. It does not provide multiboot. But a related method is provided via this link and links from it, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682 -- I think you have to create your own system in order to satisfy all three conditions in your question. See also this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier

[MultiBootUSB](https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb) is a cross platform software written in Python which allows you to install multiple live Linux distros on a USB disk non-destructively and has an option to uninstall distros. From the [MultiBootUSB Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026013858/http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/):

> **MultiBootUSB allows you to do the following**
>
> - Install multiple live Linux distros and other operating systems to a USB disk and make it bootable without erasing existing data.
> - Uninstall installed OSs later.
> - Write ISO images directly to a USB disk (GUI for Linux `dd` command).
> - Boot ISO images and USB disks directly without rebooting your system using QEMU.
> - Boot USB on UEFI/EFI systems through GRUB2 bootloader support (limited support).
>
> **Adding a persistence file**
>
> - Only distros based on Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora are supported.
> - Once you complete [Step 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026013858/http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/#creating-live-linux-on-usb-disk)
>   (Choose an ISO), MultiBootUSB will detect the type of distro and a
>   persistence size chooser slider will appear below the MultiBootUSB tab.
>
>   [image]
>
>   The maximum size of the persistence storage space is also automatically calculated
>   according to the USB disk filesystem.
> - Choose the desired persistence size by dragging the slider to the right and follow [Step
>   3](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026013858/http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/#creating-live-linux-on-usb-disk) (Click the *↓ Install distro* button)
>   as usual.
> - Once the Linux distro is installed successfully, you will find the additional persistence file under the distro install directory.
> - Reboot your system to choose your distro and a persistence menu will be added automatically to the menu entries.

Comment: Can you still use it to create the usbdata partition like mkusb does? [I already tried the french MultiSystem application (didnt work) and I was working on MultiBoot right now]

Comment: @VitorAbella, please ask specifically about the usbdata partition, and I will try to answer with enough details to help you create a system with such a partition. In general, the first partition created will be partition #1 and it will be seen by Windows, if the file system is FAT or NTFS.

Comment: @sudosus using multibootusb?

Comment: @sudodus question asked, you can sugest an edit to my question if you want. https://askubuntu.com/questions/943761/how-to-make-a-data-partition-on-multiboot-usb-flash-drive

Comment: I use USB pendrives as temporary devices: Install what I need and install something else, when I need something else. This means that I don't  keep a multiboot system up to date with new iso files. It also means that I don't bother with persistence for multiboot systems. So I don't know what would be the best way to create such a system. (I will look at your new question now ...)

Comment: @sudodus I use 32 bits and 64 bits computers. So everything I need with a single flash drive would be nice.

Comment: There is a compressed image file with a persistent live system, that boots in 32-bit and 64-bit computers, in BIOS mode and UEFI mode, even with secure boot. See these links: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Very_flexible_LXLE_16.04.2_system_.2832_bit.29_with_mkusb_version_12.1.5 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent/LXLE

Comment: @karel I have installed multibootusb. but when I intent to use this I forget the usage. How to see the manual of it's in Ubuntu?

Comment: To show the manual run the command `multibootusb -c -h` or visit the online MultiBootUSB webpage: http://multibootusb.org/page_guide/#using-mltibootusb-command-line-options to see the manual and examples of commands and also the online MultiBootUSB FAQ: http://multibootusb.org/page_faq/.

Comment: @karel: MultiBootUSB 9.2.0, Windows and Linux versions, **do not support Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04 and 20.10**. MBUSB attempts to install in ISO mode, the result upon booting is a screen full of dots. there is no Persistence slider. I think there is a problem with GRUB 2.04.

Comment: The project now seems abandoned, and their site has been taken over by cybersquatters.

Answer (score 3):

### Ventoy

**Ventoy** is installed to a USB disk in seconds.

After installation, OS ISO's can be copy/pasted, dragged/dropped to the USB.

No further setup is required, (unless adding persistence).

MS Windows installer disks can be be added.

Linux OS can be added.

FreeBSD, etc, etc can be added.

"90%+ distros in distrowatch.com are supported.
550+ ISO files are tested".

There is Windows and Linux versions.

It is simpler to use than Etcher.

https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

For Ventoy persistence plugin see:

https://www.ventoy.net/en/plugin_persistence.html

Comment: +1; Ventoy is a new tool and it is easy to use, so it is relevant to add this answer to an old question.

Comment: @sudodus I think MultiBootUSB has been abandoned and is not working with 20.04 and higher. I think Sundar may have had problems with GRUB 2.04. Too bad I really liked it. Sundar is an inspiration to me.

Comment: Maybe you can write directly to Sundar and ask or encourage him?

Comment: @sudodu:s I will make a note to do that as soon as I send you results for 12.6.6 and 2.8.4 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this. Here's a short list:

1. [Multiboot USB](https://multibootusb.org/page_download/) as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/943477/225694)
2. [MultiSystem](https://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/)
3. [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
4. [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/) (Windows only)
5. [grml-rescueboot](https://wiki.grml.org/doku.php?id=rescueboot) (my preference)

I've tried all of these and found them to be relatively simple and easy to use.

Sources:

Experience

https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso

https://wiki.grml.org/doku.php?id=rescueboot

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Create-a-Multi-boot-USB-Stick-with-MultiSystem

https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/faq/

http://wiki.grml.org/doku.php?id=persistency