# How to make a data partition on multiboot usb flash Drive?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, mkusb

I successfully created a multiboot persistent USB flash drive with [multibootusb](https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb). The persistent storage was limited (4GB).

However, how can I add a data partition that can be read on Ubuntu and windows?

If `multibootusb` is not the right application to do that, I accept other suggestions.

Comment: I have only been able to install MultiBootUSB, (by Sundar Ima), on the first partition of a flash drive, but it does not mind sharing the first partition with Windows.

Comment: Thanks for this information C.S.Cameron. It means that we should not bother with another (and separate) first partition when using MultiBootUSB. (I am removing my previous comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot the MultiBootUSB drive.

Open Nautilus as root, go to computer/cdrom and make a folder named Shared Data.

Save any stuff you want to share with a Windows computer there, You will need to be root to access the folder.

When plugged into a computer running Windows, the Shared Data folder will be accessible when the drive is opened in Explorer.

Windows can only see the first partition on a flash drive and MultiBootUSB needs to be installed on the first partition, but they can share it.

Mkusb will create a Ubuntu flash drive that boots using grub2.

It uses a FAT32 boot partition, a ISO9660 read only OS partition, an ext casper-rw persistence partition, (not limited to 4GB), and a NTFS partition that can be used by Linux or Windows.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

You can split the casper-rw persistence partition into  casper-rw plus home-rw if you want more persistence options.

It is a little work to turn a mkusb drive a multibooter but it can be done by editing grub.cfg to boot iso's located in the usbdata partition.

Up to 14.04 it was possible to add a persistent partition to syslinux type Live drives such as Startup Disk Creator and Unetbootin make, now days this just results in BusyBox.

Comment: let me see if I understood. You suggested 2 solutions, one with multibootusb and another with mkusb?

Comment: Yes, MultiBootUSB can share a partition with Windows but it's persistence is limited to one 4GB casper-rw and one 4GB home-rw persistence file for each menuentry. The partition on a mbusb drive can not be easily modified. Mkusb is suggested as an alternate that has more persistence options than mbusb.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GParted` to partition the drive with a `Fat32` partition for the live usb and a `ntfs` partition for your data.

[described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive)