# How do I integrate an existing Ventoy Disk into Grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I use Grub to boot Ubuntu and Windows.
Added now an additional SSD that was set up with Ventoy (latest version).

I spent hours today trying to find instructions on how to include Ventoy in my Grub menu.
Unfortunately, none of the many variations worked.

Who knows how I can integrate this new Ventoy drive into Grub step by step ?

Comment: eh what do you mean? Ventoy is tool to put ISO on USB drives and then boot the ISO from it. Grub does not come into play here

Comment: UEFI boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in the ESP. Do you have that file from ventoy in the ESP on that drive? You then may be able to use chainloader in grub to load the bootx64.efi or if in grub mode a configfile to another grub.cfg. But if booting multiple ISO and using grub you really do not need ventoy. Just use grub2's loop mount to directly load ISO. I just did that with 23.10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293484/how-can-i-create-a-multi-boot-usb-with-persistence & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782

Comment: Apparently there is a communication problem here.

First of all, Ventoy can be used on hard disks.
It is no different than a USB stick.

Grub is used EXCLUSIVELY to run my operating systems.
The Ventoy disk is now to be integrated into this selection screen.

I have a whole collection of images that should find their place here. 
It would be too much trouble to generate the right start sequence for grub for each image file.

What I need is the command lines to boot the above boot partition using grub.

Comment: Poorly formatted chainloader example. https://forum.zorin.com/t/chainloading-ventoy/25602

Comment: This is it, thank you

Comment: @HardyThiergart Would you please show how you got Ventoy integrated into GRUB with Ubuntu?  If you've invented that particular wheel...

Answer (score 0):

To connect Grub with Ventoy I use the Grub Customizer with the entries

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
insmod fat
insmod exfat
insmod ntfs
insmod chain
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid xxxx-xxxx (= UUID of the Ventoy boot drive)
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/grub.efi
```

oldfred had already linked an integration with grub.
This is how the whole thing works in my system.