# Installing Ubuntu or Trisquel on an SSD from a HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

So I have a 500gb HDD currently split 50 50 between Ubuntu and Windows. I have a 120 GB which I would like to give a fresh install of Trisquel or Ubuntu, then expand the Windows partition to occupy the whole HDD. I don't have a USB handy, but I have my iso downloaded on the linux partition of my HDD. Is there a way to install it to the SSD from the HDD without using a USB drive?

Comment: If you have grub booting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/845192/can-i-create-a-dedicated-partition-for-gparted-and-launch-from-grub
This will boot an ISO from a hard drive or any second drive or flash drive
ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive - drs305
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples  vmlinuz may be vmlinuz.efi in some versions of ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines)