# Grub EFI USB ISOs unable to find live medium

Tags: grub2, live-usb, iso, grub-efi

**My goal:**

Install `grub2` EFI in a USB to be multiboot with ISOs.
I partition the USB, 1 FAT to install EFI, and another EXT4 for the ISOs.

**What works:**

Install `grub` in the USB from a live linux using `chroot`:

```
sudo grub-install --force --removable --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/media/user/BOOT/ /dev/sdb1
```

The USB boots the `grub`.

**What does not work:**

I add the menuentry, for example of clonezilla:

```
menuentry "Clonezilla live (Default settings, VGA 800x600)"{
  loopback loop (hd0,msdos2)/clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live iso-scan/filename=(hd0,msdos2)/clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

... but I always get the error

> Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

But from the `grub` console I can check that the paths and names are correct.
I've bee all over the internet and tried many things, other USBs, different computers, different ISOs (Linux Mint, Linux Lite)...but always fall in the same error.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Do not know clonezilla live ISO but i686 would be 32 bit in Ubuntu and not UEFI bootable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines

Comment: This works for me as a multiboot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1053051#1053051 Persistence can be added if desired. The ISO9660 and casper-rw partitions can be removed also.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. I've been on those links (I've seen every link on the subject he). The clonezilla image has an EFI folder, but I should try with the 64bit version. But... I tried with a Linux Mint 19 64bit and the result was the same. What I haven't tried is with gpt partitions.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thank you. It's not just about being able to create a multiboot usb, I can use YUMI (also) for example, but I just want to learn if I can accomplish this without any "extra" software.

Comment: Some of my examples here, but I use a separate configfile in a /ISO folder where I put all the ISO. Biggest issue I always have is getting path correct. And if hard drive getting drive correct. Plugging in flash drive, but  booting from HDD, changes my drive order. My hard drive path is different than my flash drive paths so I cannot just copy. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines & https://askubuntu.com/questions/845192/can-i-create-a-dedicated-partition-for-gparted-and-launch-from-grub

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
menuentry "Clonezilla live (Default settings, VGA 800x600)"{
  loopback loop (hd0,msdos2)/clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live iso-scan/filename=(hd0,msdos2)/clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

for

```
set root='hd0,1'

menuentry "Clonezilla live (Default settings, VGA 800x600)"{
  loopback loop /clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live iso-scan/filename=(hd0,msdos2)/clonezilla-live-2.6.0-37-i686.iso
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

... and it works fine.