# How can I boot from a Windows iso in Ubuntu without burning it to CD/DVD/Disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

How do I boot from a Windows 10 Installer (ISO) in Ubuntu 17.10 without burning to a CD/DVD/Disk?

I made a NTFS Partition of the C:\ Drive to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu but GRUB won't let me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to boot from non-Ubuntu live ISO images like Fedora or CentOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141940/how-to-boot-from-non-ubuntu-live-iso-images-like-fedora-or-centos)

Comment: @Fabby: I can see no answer there that would work with windows. They all rely on the `linux` or `linux16` commands of Grub and I don't think they'd work here.