# How to create recovery partition to reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have an HP laptop that came with Windows 7 installed with a recovery partition which was accessible through the boot menu in the same way you could access the BIOS. I wanted to be able to create an Ubuntu recovery partition that would be able to be accessed and used to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, if I ever need to, just like an HP or Dell would come with a Windows recovery partition.  Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: I'd file this at brainstorm.ubuntu.com.

Comment: So does that mean that it is not now something that is already possible?

Comment: The "duplicate" question is about a recovery partition that can be used to fix Ubuntu without reinstalling. This question is about recovery partitions that reinstall the operating system.

Comment: See the accepted answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make a partition backup is to use **dd** with **cron**. You can create the task that will run automatically in the time you want to.

The idea discribed here: [click me](http://www.backuphowto.info/linux-backup-hard-disk-clone-dd)

How to use cron: [click here](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Comment: I think the author wants to know how to create a partition that you can reinstall Ubuntu from, not how to make backups.

Comment: and what's the difference? =)
if you make backup with dd the only you have to do is boot with cd/dvd image of ubuntu and restore backup to your partition (/dev/sda1 or the other)

Comment: `dd` can make an exact copy of the OS which can be later used again, that's what the Windows recovery partitions do, no? and if it is, `dd` is actually better as it lets you continue where you left off.

Comment: The windows recovery partition is basically the windows installation DVD, but on the hard drive. The windows recovery partition is not a backup of what you had before, nor is it a tool to make/restore backups.

Comment: Yes user530873... I want a recovery partition to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, if I ever need to, just like an HP or Dell would come with a Windoze recovery partition. I believe this is something that should be possible and I can't imagine I am the only one who has ever thought of it. Any ideas?