# Help booting ubuntu iso from the hard drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, grub4dos

I am currently using Windows 7.

I downloaded the ubuntu's iso file from the official site. 
I don't currently have a pendrive and my laptop doesn't have any CD/DVD drive either.

I found a tutorial to boot iso files from windows boot loader using "EasyBCD". I followed it and restarted and it showed me the option to run the ubuntu's image file.

Edited:

It runs now, the ubuntu logo loads and reaches the command line again with this

> (initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system
>   .

The process is stuck here and I'm a complete newbie to Linux/ubuntu.
Please help me out.

Comment: Can you install unetbootin?

Comment: Edited the post with updates. Please check again :)

Comment: It is possible to install Ubuntu this way, but it is nearly impossible for a newbie. I do not remember exactly how it is done, but it is too complex.

Comment: agreed with pilot6; short version: 1. create partition size of ISO plus a few Mb. 2. Put ISO on partition. 3. reboot. 4. in grub set partition to boot from it. The long one is ... long... and riddled with specific commands that need tweaking. I would wait for a pendrive to arrive ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is looking for a software solution to a hardware problem (no USB stick, CD/DVD drive)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a bootable live cd disk image mounted on the hard drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive)