# Custom Recovery disk containing ubuntu16.04 and Clonezilla together

Tags: boot, live-usb, clonezilla

To cope with unexpected crashes, I decided to dedicate a 2GB usb device for storing ubuntu 16.04 live usb, so that I can boot from the live usb and fix some boot issues or Grub related issues.

I made another bootable disk burned with clonezilla so that I can recover from a previously backed up image if the system really got messed up from my crazy experiments, in a way that is not fixable using live usb( Or if I want to use it in another machine to fix boot issues or clone my disk image in a new machine)

Now, the question is, Can I use a single usb to store both clonezilla and the live ubuntu 16.04 image ? May be using different partitions on the same usb?

Comment: There are a few solution for that, the most popular being Multisystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a bootable live cd disk image mounted on the hard drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive)

Comment: @Fabby I don't want to boot from the hard disk. What I need is a rescue usb to be used in the scenarios I mentioned in my question (including hard disk failure.)

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing: you should copy the Clonezilla image to your Live USB and just add it to the grub menu and that will solve your problem!  **:-)**  *Your Live USB is just another form of hard drive!*  **;-)**

Comment: Which Grub menu you are talking about? On the live usb, there is no grub menu. And even if I access and edit the grub menu in a live session, the changes won't persist as per my knowledge.

Comment: I think I am looking for something as @CelticWarrior suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a Bootable USB with Ubuntu and CloneZilla and maybe other rescue disk on the same stick, then you can chose for YUMI Pendrivelinux Multiboot USB

**Creating a YUMI MultiBoot USB Flash Drive (Linux)**

1. Open a terminal and type sudo su Type fdisk -l (and note which
   device is your USB Drive)
2. Type fdisk /dev/sdx (replacing x with your actual usb device)
3. Type d (to delete the existing partition)
4. Type n (to create a new partition)
5. Type p (for primary partition)
6. Type 1 (to create the first partition)
7. Press Enter (to use the first cylinder)
8. Press Enter again (to use the default value as the last cylinder)
9. Type a (for active)
10. Type 1 (to mark the first partition active "bootable")
11. Type t (for partition type) Type c (to use fat32 partition)
12. Type w (to write the changes and close fdisk)

**Create a Fat32 Filesystem on the USB Flash Drive**

13. Type `umount /dev/sdx1` (to unmount the mounted
     partition)
14. Type `mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n MULTIBOOT /dev/sdx1` (to format
     the partition as fat32)
15. Remove and reinsert your USB flash drive, or remount it

**Install WINE**

16. To install WINE from within an Ubuntu operating environment, open a
     terminal and type `sudo apt install wine` and press enter.
17. Once WINE is installed, Download YUMI from the official
     pendrivelinux site
18. launch YUMI as you normally would by simply clicking `the
     YUMI-{version-downloaded}.exe`
19. Follow the steps from the YUMI GUI to add ass many distros as you
     want from ISO files
20. Remote the drive after you finish adding isos and boot from it

You will have a **YUMI MultiBoot USB Boot Menu** on screen and you can chose whatever distro want to boot into.

Additional notes: all info above can also be found also on the pendrivelinux web page and much more.