# Install Ubuntu directly

Tags: system-installation

Is it possible to install Ubuntu via an existing os with a shell but is completely unbootable, like obtain a fresh unmodified installed version of ubuntu (not the iso, the result of the installation of that iso) then copy it to an empty partition then manage to get it to boot via grub (as I am un able to access the cd rom from my rom nor do anything with iso files from my os nor with my android)

Comment: Using a USB flash drive isn't an option?

Answer (score 0):

> via an existing os with a shell ...  to an empty partition then manage to get it to boot via grub

If that OS is Ubuntu: yes. But you technically do not even need a OS on the system to do this: you can use a live session to do this.

- boot up a live session
- install and start gparted.
- create a  partition minimal the size of the ISO (2Gb should be more than enough).
- put the ISO stored on disk into that partition.

Also see on examples on how to setup grub:

- [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux)
- [Using a bootable live cd disk image mounted on the hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive)

Comment: Ok, ill try that

Comment: So just to be clear I can do this directly from android x86 installation cd shell n grub1.5 menu

Comment: where does "android x86 installation cd shell" come from? That was not in the question and would make this off topic. And no: not without correct firmware.

Comment: I only have grub1.5 ;-;

Comment: Basically the android x86 shell is a slimmed down version of the linux shell but it still has most linux commands although not all commands are present (eg like the growfs command) but it should function the same

Comment: Eg it has gparted, fdisk, cat, mkdir, ls and other linux commands

Comment: It is very similar to linux but I cannot access the cdrom to burn files to it, so I need to try n boot the iso from the hdd (or possibly obtain a pre installed sda with the linux iso already installed then copy to sda n add to grub then boot into it