# Trying to install Ubuntu without usb. Want to replace Windows

Tags: system-installation

I am looking to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I don't have any USB drives laying around and the only way to install Ubuntu I've seen so far without a USB is to dual-boot. I don't want to dual-boot; I want to full-on replace Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway you'll have to boot from some external drive. The easiest way is a USB drive. You can't install Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you!

Comment: Borrow an empty USB drive from a friend.

Comment: You can however create an empty 2Gb-ish partition, store the ISO from windows into that partition and boot that ISO from your BIOS ;)

Comment: Install Ubuntu to replace Windows without need for USB: https://askubuntu.com/a/1357732/43926