# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Air 1,1

Tags: macbook, mbr, gpt

I've wanted to give my MacBook Air 1,1 a new life with Ubuntu. It seems this computer [has a 64-bit CPU](https://igotoffer.com/apple/macbook-air-1-1), so it should run current versions of Ubuntu.

However, when I try to I install the ISO to the USB stick on MacOS, it's automatically sets to the MBR Partition Scheme, because it runs 32 bit MacOS.
I cannot install Balena Etcher, and I don't have another Mac, so I cannot install it over there.

Does anyone know if there is any way to create a bootable USB stick with GPT/GUID Partion Scheme in my current situation, so that I can install Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have a DVD drive? Otherwise, do you have access to any other computer to make the live USB? Any other Windows/Mac computer should work.

Comment: Since actually creating an USB stick on 32-bit MacOS is probably a long shot here, you would likely be best helped with access to an existing Ubuntu machines somewhere, where you could create a bootable USB.

Comment: Also, check if UNetbootin works. http://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview   But do note you may need updated versions of software to write 20.10 & later correctly... ie. older software may write only older ISOs of Ubuntu products correctly.  Any formatting on the thumb-drive is usually overwritten (thus creating a GPT scheme on thumb-drive prior to write of ISO is wasted energy; if re-creating the ISO during write; you need updated software for releases since mid-2020).

Answer (score 2):

The following outlines a procedure for installing a 64 bit BIOS booting Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Mac with 32 bit EFI and 64 bit processors. A 32 bit Debian is first installed, because the Debian installer can 32 bit EFI boot from a flash drive and install a BIOS booting GRUB. This GRUB is then used to BIOS boot the 64 bit Ubuntu installer from the internal drive.

1. *Install a 32 bit BIOS booting Debian.*

   Follow steps 1 through 4 given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16/409448#409448). This answer used the current 32 bit Debian installation ISO file, which includes additional software for graphical video hardware. This file can be found [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/11.7.0+nonfree/i386/iso-dvd/). At present, this file is named `firmware-11.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso`.
2. *Create a 64 bit Ubuntu installer on an internal drive partition.*

   Start by booting to Debian. If the Mac does not boot to Debian (via Grub) by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, login as root. Otherwise, login using the default username, open a Terminal window and enter the command shown below.

   ```
   su --login
   ```

   Enter a following command to permit writing to the `/dev/sda3` partition, which has been assigned the `/installation` mount point.

   ```
   chmod a+w /installation
   ```

   Transfer, to the `/installation` mount point, the current 64 bit Ubuntu LTS installation ISO file. This file can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). At present, this would be the file named `ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`. Below are various ways to transfer this file. Choose one way or find another way.

   > Note: A choice below can depend on which predefined collections of software are currently installed.

   - Use another computer to download and transfer the files to a FAT formatted USB flash drive. Use either the `cp` command or the Files application to copy from the USB flash drive to the `/installation` mount point.
   - Use another computer to download the files. Use `sftp` on this other computer to transfer the files to the `/installation` mount point on the Mac. Enter the command `hostname -I` on the Mac to get an IP address.
   - Use the FireFox ESR application to download the files from the web. Use either the `cp` command or the Files application to copy the downloaded files to the `/installation` mount point.

   When finished, shutdown the Mac. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, then enter the command below instead.

   ```
   shutdown -P now
   ```

   Remove any USB flash drives that may be plugged into the Mac.
3. *Replace the 32 bit Debian with a 64 bit Ubuntu.* Start by booting to Grub. If the Mac does not boot to Grub by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, press the <kbd>C</kbd> key.

   [image: GNU GRUB]

   Enter the commands given below to boot from the `/dev/sda3` partition. This sequence of commands was derived the question [Using a bootable live cd disk image mounted on the hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive).

   ```
   insmod iso9660
   set isofile="ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
   loopback loop (hd0,3)/$isofile
   linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/$isofile noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
   boot
   ```

   Proceed with the installation of Ubuntu. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `Something else`, then `Continue`.

   [image]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `/dev/sda1`, then `Change…`.

   [image]

   Except for the `Size`, configure the partition setting as shown below. **Do not change the size.** When finished, select `OK`.

   [image]

   Even though the size was not changed, the following popup may appear. If so, select `Continue`.

   [image]

   For this example, the result is shown below. Select `Install Now`.

   [image]

   Even though no EFI System Partition is needed, the following popup may appear. If so, select `Continue`.

   [image]

   Continue and finish installing Ubuntu.
4. *Remove the partition with the installation files and extend the Ubuntu partition.*

   Follow step 7 given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16/409448#409448) after making the following changes.

   - Omit the `su` command at the beginning.
   - Only enter one `exit` command at the end.

   Note: In the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16/409448#409448), Debian is being used instead of Ubuntu.

### Setting BIOS Booting as the Default

If a BIOS booting Ubuntu is the only operating system installed on a Mac, then the Mac should automatically boot to Ubuntu. However, if BIOS booting has not be set as the default, there may be a delay before booting begins. Otherwise, the Mac Startup Manager can be used to boot Debian. To set BIOS booting as the default, boot from an OS X (macOS) installation DVD or USB flash drive, open a Terminal window and enter the command given below.

```
bless --device /dev/disk0 --setBoot --legacy
```

The version of OS X (macOS) chosen must be compatible with your Mac. The instructions for creating a Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) installation USB flash drive can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive/400475#400475).